# What happens to shift-alt-f[1..12] in Gnome desktop?

Tags: xorg

When I key in ctl-alt-f[1..12], I am taken to VT1[ ..12] (Virtual Terminal 1..12).  This works wherever I am.
From a Virtual Terminal that is not running a graphical environment, shift-alt-f[1..12] takes me to Virtual Terminal [13..24].  However, if I use the same key-combination from any Virtual Termial that is running a graphical environment - Gnome, KDE, XFCE or LXDE, these key combinations are simply ignored.  It doesn't matter which VT the graphical environment is running in, the keystrokes are still sent to that great bit-bucket in the sky.
What is happening here - is the X-server somehow eating these keystrokes?  Is there any way I can get X-server not to eat them?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the X server wants the ctrl added to switch VTs.  Hold down ctrl if you are on a VT running X.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure I understand. Ctrl-alt-f[1-6] take you to non-graphical VTs. ctrl-alt-f[7-9] take you to graphical VTs.